# ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT When Accessing An IIS Website From Another Machine On The Network

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm receiving an **ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT** error when trying to access the Default.aspx webpage from another computer.

I have setup a local website using IIS - from the machine where the website has been hosted using IIS, I am able to navigate to the Default.aspx webpage on the local browser.

I have setup bindings to an IP address so I can access it from other devices on the network. I have also setup the firewall to unblock all ports so I am able to access this.

**Problem:**

When I navigate on the local machine where I have the website hosted using IIS, I am able to see the Default.aspx webpage.

However, now that I have binded an IP in IIS to the website, I want to be able to reach it from another PC on the network.

Currently I am able to access all the webpages in sub directories and also the main directory for the website using:

- 192.168.1.165:81/SubDirectory/File.aspx
- 192.168.1.165:81/FileInLocalDirectory.aspx

**BUT** I am not able to access the homepage named 192.168.1.165:81/Default.aspx.

I have no idea why. The error I receive is

```
192.168.1.165 sent an invalid response. 
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT
```

I don't know what the issue is. I don't know if there is something in Default.aspx that is stopping the webpage from being displayed when trying to be accessed from a machine and not the local machine.

@LexLi

[image: Packets being transmitted]

Comment: Use the browser's developer tools or Fiddler to see what redirection packets are sent, or no one cannot guess it out.

Comment: Hi @LexLi - It doesn't seem as though any packets are being sent. Attached a picture.

Comment: Redirection related things are not easy to troubleshoot. Clear browser cache so it won't be fooled by previous 301 redirection responses, and then try again with Network tab opened. Sometimes Fiddler or Wireshark show more information for you to dig, so you might try them as well. The more you know of the underlying conversation, the easier to catch the culprit.